# Split multiple times in Tableau for Join Condition (Datasource or Worksheet)

Tags: tableau-api

I have two EXCEL files and trying to use the customer id from one file to match the customer id's that are included as a part of 2nd file which includes a 300 character. The Customer id in the second file is embedded as a part of the 300 characters.

I need to find-out how I can take the customer ids from the first file (customer file) to join them with the second file that includes the customer transactions.

I can use the Datasource Join options and establish one condition such as below,
Customer ID = SPLIT([Field Number],"_",1) but since this condition is not enough and I need multiple SPLITS to get the customer ID based on other conditions using SPLIT, it is not working within the DataSource Tab-> Join Options.

HOW CAN I DO MULTIPLE SPLITS like

> Customer ID = SPLIT([Field Number],"*",1) OR Customer ID =
>   SPLIT([Field Number],"GET*",6) OR Customer ID = SPLIT([Field
>   Number],"TEACH",1)

If I need to do this within the Worksheet, using the calculated field, please let me know how I can use the Calcuated Field option but include all the conditions..

Thanks in advance for your time

Customer File:
[Picture of the firest file includings the Customer IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ldLF.png)

Transction file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnBnj.png)

Comment: I'm basically trying to do the following in one Calculation, if contains([Long String Field], "[CUSTOMER IDs]") then 1 else 0 END. Long String is from a different file. CUSTOMER IDs are from a different EXCEL File. Two different EXCEL Files. One includes the CUSTOMER IDs without any issues in a Column. The other file includes the CUSTOMER ID within the 300 TEXT File.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample date?

Comment: Customer ID in Customer File A675B6 OR N89YT6 (There are many of them) Now, Customer ID in the second file which is a transaction file. 987342A675B6HGCCCCCCCCC OR XCC174YCDN89YT665777. So as you can see the two Customer IDs are embedded as a part of The Transaction File Long Text Field. I don't know how to do replies so I just put it in the comments.  Thanks a lot

Comment: please, update your question giving two simple dataset well formatted (not in comment).... this would help a lot

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't see an Update Option to reply to this thread.

Comment: So I made a change to the original request. added two pictures showing the two files. Thanks

Comment: In order to have a better understanding of your need, please provide samples for your 2 sample datasources and expected resulting dataset